# How to access values of AbstractMap.SimpleEntry in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

For example, I have

```
List<SimpleEntry<String, String>> myPairList = 
                                   new ArrayList<SimpleEntry<String, String>>();
```

How do I access its entries (the key and the value) through

```
<c:forEach items="${myList }" var="myPair">
   <c:set var="key" value="????????" />
   <c:set var="value" value="????????" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) say about the class SimpleEntry? It has a `getKey()` getter, and a `getValue()` getter.

How do we access a property (i.e. a getter) from the JSP EL? `obj.propertyName`

So you just need

```
<c:set var="key" value="${myPair.key}" />
<c:set var="value" value="${myPair.value}" />
```